# git describe --tags behaviour

Tags: git, tags

I want to build a build flow in VS and want to use the tag.

I'm using `git describe --tags` to get the latest tag, but it's not always working. Here's an example:

```
me@pc MINGW64 /d/temp (master)
$ git tag
TAG_1
TAG_2
TAG_3
TAG_4

me@pc MINGW64 /d/temp (master)
$ git describe --tags
TAG_4

me@pc MINGW64 /d/temp (master)
$ git tag TAG_5

me@pc MINGW64 /d/temp (master)
$ git tag TAG_6

me@pc MINGW64 /d/temp (master)
$ git describe --tags
TAG_4

me@pc MINGW64 /d/temp (master)
$ git describe --abbrev=0 --tags
TAG_4

me@pc MINGW64 /d/temp (master)
$ git tag
TAG_1
TAG_2
TAG_3
TAG_4
TAG_5
TAG_6

me@pc MINGW64 /d/temp (master)
$ git --version
git version 2.33.1.windows.1
```

I wanted the describe --tags command to display TAG_6 after I'd added that one. Sometimes it works, sometimes it gets confused like this. It's a local Windows 10 repo in the test.

How can I reliably get the latest tag on the branch?

Thanks in advance. Steve

Comment: Unannotated tags doesn't really have a timestamp, they just exist. While the actual file on disk might have a timestamp, this is not used, as it doesn't necessarily represent the actual timestamp of when the tag was created. For instance, if you clone a repository, the tags might be stored in `.git\packed-refs`, which only lists commit id + tag name. Conjecture: Since the unannotated tags doesn't have a timestamp, nor do they have any inherent ordering. Git will return the first one it found, for whatever reason. "whatever reason" might be due to the timestamp on disk, but that may be wrong.